# Compute the log10 of the image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

how Compute the log10 of the image in matlab and what mean log10 of image?
and image is graylevel.
for example:

a=imread('image.jpg');

im2bw(a,log10);

i want know the log10 how to effect on image?

Comment: If you can't define what it means to take the log10 of an image, why are you trying to do it?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal that you want to achieve?

Comment: Example for how: `I = imread('cameraman.tif');I = im2double(I);J = log10(I);imshow(J, [])`. Image is brighter (only after linear stretching) and ["logarithmic"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/pixlog.htm). Actual values of J are negative.

Comment: thanks for answer the question Rotem. I made a mistake in imshow(J, []). i use ( imshow(J);) for show image and The image was black.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. The effect of the logarithm on intensity values.

Assume you have a greyscale image. Let's use the `cameraman.tif` image provided by matlab.

```
Img = imread ('cameraman.tif');
```

This image is a uint8 image (i.e. it can take possible intensity values in the 0-255 range), but in fact this particular image has a minimum intensity value of 7 and maximum of 253. This is useful to demonstrate the effect of the logarithm, since there is no value of 0 (which would result in 'minus infinity' in the logarithm output).

So, to demonstrate what happens to intensities when you take the logarithm, let's first take a linear range of intensities from the minimum to the maximum value, and also the logarithm of that range.

```
Range    = double (min (Img(:)) : max (Img(:)));      
LogRange = log10 (Range);
```

Now let's normalise both in the [0,1] interval and plot the ranges.

```
NormalisedRange    = mat2gray (Range); 
NormalisedLogRange = mat2gray (LogRange);

subplot (1, 2, 1); plot (NormalisedRange);    axis tight square; title ('Normalised intensity values');
subplot (1, 2, 2); plot (NormalisedLogRange); axis tight square; title ('Normalised Log of intensity values');
```

[image]

So, if you apply a logarithmic transformation, you shift intensities 'up', i.e. you make pixels brighter; the darker the pixel before the transformation, the larger the effect.

## 2. The effect of the logarithm visually

Let's see how this looks on the actual image and its logarithmic transformation (both normalised into the [0,1] range as above).
We will also examine the histogram of each image, i.e. the frequency of each intensity value in the [0,1] range.

```
LogImg           = log10 (double (Img));
NormalisedImg    = mat2gray (Img);
NormalisedLogImg = mat2gray (LogImg);

subplot (2, 2, 1); imshow (NormalisedImg, [0, 1]);    axis image off; title ('Normalised Image');
subplot (2, 2, 2); imshow (NormalisedLogImg, [0, 1]); axis image off; title ('Normalised LogImage');
subplot (2, 2, 3); imhist (NormalisedImg); 
subplot (2, 2, 4); imhist (NormalisedLogImg);
```

[image]

You can see that the effect of the transformation has been to 'brighten' the picture up, and in particular, it has particularly improved the contrast in the previously darker areas (e.g. the man's features are a lot clearer now).

Obviously, the downside is that contrast has worsened in the 'bright' areas, since previously darker pixels are now bunched closer together with brighter ones (e.g. the distinction between the building and the skyline is less clear now).

You can also confirm from the histograms that the intensity distribution has largely shifted towards brighter values.